# Stash list empty on refresh

Tags: stash, caching

**Edit**

After some debugging, the issue seems to be around the text content of the tweet or Instagram photo. Looking in the database, if I save the caption or tweet text, the data suddenly cuts of in the parameters column.

---

I'm trying to create a social media wall pulling in photos from instagram and tweets from twitter with a certain tag. I create a list for each network (Twitter, instagram, EE) and then we join them lists.

I've got this working fine, the tweets and photos pull in fine, but when I try to cache the stash lists, I get some odd behaviour.

On the first load, it works great, the list is created and the list is saved in the database. If I then refresh that page, all of a sudden the list is either empty, has less results or has tags not rendering.

If I tell Stash to replace the list every time, then it works. Any idea's whats happening here?

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="instagram--{embed:term}{get:ig}" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" save="yes" scope="site" replace="no" refresh="60"}
    {exp:ig_picpuller:tagged_media user_id="1" limit="12" max_id="{get:ig}" tag="{embed:term}"}

        {!-- Instagram Data --}

    {/exp:ig_picpuller:tagged_media}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:set_list name="twitter--{embed:term}{get:tweet}" parse_tags="yes" match="#^(?!\s*$).+#" against="image" parse_depth="2" parse_conditionals="yes" save="yes" scope="site" replace="no" refresh="60"}
    {exp:ce_tweet:search q="#{embed:term}" count="100" max_id="{get:tweet}"}
        {statuses}

            {!-- Twitter Data --}

        {/statuses}
    {/exp:ce_tweet:search}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:set_list name="posts--{embed:term}" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" parse_depth="10"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="channelName" limit="300" dynamic="no" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}

        {!-- EE Data --}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:join_lists name="media--{embed:term}" lists="twitter--{embed:term}{get:tweet},instagram--{embed:term}{get:ig},posts--{embed:term}"}



{exp:stash:get_list name="media--{embed:term}" limit="20" offset="{get:offset}" unique="id" orderby="date" sort="desc" sort_type="numeric"}
    {!-- Play with the list --}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, as mentioned in my edit, the problem was to do with the text content from the tweet or Instagram caption. I simply JSON Encoded/Decoded the text and everything started working again.